# Applying two different rate limit policies to the same endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rate-limiting

I'm using the new [rate limit library for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/rate-limit?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and can't figure out how to apply multiple policies to the same endpoint. What I want to achieve is the following: I want to limit the amount of requests to an endpoint based on client IP and at the same time limit the total amount of request from all clients to the same endpoint. So for endpoint `api/ping` it should be limited to for instance 100 request/min for a single IP, but 1000 requests/min total across all IPs.

Currently I'm only limiting based on IP:

```
services.AddRateLimiter(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Api", httpContext =>
                RateLimitPartition.GetSlidingWindowLimiter(httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress,
                    _ => new SlidingWindowRateLimiterOptions
                    {
                        AutoReplenishment = true,
                        PermitLimit = 100,
                        QueueLimit = 0,
                        Window = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                        SegmentsPerWindow = 20
                    }));

            options.OnRejected = async (context, token) =>
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 429;
                await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
                    "Too many requests. Please try again in a few moments. " +
                    "Read more about our rate limits at https://.",
                    cancellationToken: token);
            };
        });
```

I understand there is something like `PartitionedRateLimiter.CreateChained()`, but this requires each limiter to have a partition key (i.e. client IP address), but for my second policy I don't have a partition key since it's the total for all users. It would be perfect if I could do something like:

```
            PartitionedRateLimiter.CreateChained(
                PartitionedRateLimiter.Create<HttpContext, string>(httpContext =>
                    RateLimitPartition.GetSlidingWindowLimiter(httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
                        _ => new SlidingWindowRateLimiterOptions
                        {
                            AutoReplenishment = true,
                            PermitLimit = 100,
                            QueueLimit = 0,
                            Window = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                            SegmentsPerWindow = 20
                        })),
                PartitionedRateLimiter.Create<HttpContext, string>(httpContext =>
                    RateLimitPartition.GetSlidingWindowLimiter(NO PARTITION KEY HERE,
                        _ => new SlidingWindowRateLimiterOptions
                        {
                            AutoReplenishment = true,
                            PermitLimit = 1000,
                            QueueLimit = 0,
                            Window = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                            SegmentsPerWindow = 20
                        })));
```

It's also not possible to apply multiple policies by using something like `[EnableRateLimiting("Policy1", "Policy2")]` on my controller.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if you ever found an answer for this but I needed something similar and ended up creating a custom implementation for IRateLimiterPolicy. In my GetPartition implementation I just nest my rate limiter partitions and then just use a single policy on the endpoint. My issue is I want to apply my policy globally but haven't found a way to do that since I need to use some custom services and GlobalLimiter doesn't appear to have access to IServiceProvider.